# Is there a relativistic version of Navier-Stokes equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, magnetohydrodynamics

Just as the title says, is there a relativistic version of Navier-Stokes equations?

In electromagnetic hydrodynamics it would be very useful to have relativistic version of Navier-Stokes equations, although I couldn't find one

Comment: The relativistic version of Navier-Stokes equations is a quite different theory called Israel-Stewart hydrodynamics ("relativistic Navier-Stokes" are known as "Eckart" or "Landau" relativistic hydrodynamics, but this naive relativistic generalization of Navier-Stokes does not work, it is highly unstable and acausal, so the more advanced and complex formulation of Israel-Stewart is needed).

Comment: Possibly interesting: "Relativistic theories of dissipative fluids"
J. Math. Phys. 36, 4226 (1995); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.530958
Robert Geroch

Comment: @robphy yes, this paper of Geroch is a seminal work!

Comment: MHD is typically derived using Eulerian flows, which neglect viscosity, rather than NS equations. Including viscosity in such a scenario is generally called "Extended MHD" or something akin to that (with the inviscid case generally called "Ideal MHD").

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I expand my previous comment. **Yes, there are relativistic versions of the Navier-Stokes equation:** They extend to special (or general) relativity the usual Navier-Stokes equations coupled to heat conduction (i.e., [energy diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics_(fluid_mechanics)), see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/216366/226902)). You can find them in several famous books, in particular:

[Landau, Fluid Mechanics](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eOBbAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (volume 6 of the theoretical physics course). In the chapter dedicated to relativistic hydrodynamics, you find the famous relativistic version of the Navier-Stokes equation in the so-called "**Landau** frame". See, e.g., [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/62973/226902).

[Weinberg, Gravitation and Cosmology](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Gravitation_and_Cosmology.html?id=XLbvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y): here you can find the relativistic generalization of Navier-Stokes in the so-called "**Eckart** frame" (chapter 11).

The problem is that both these "naive" relativistic generalizations of Navier-Stokes do **not** work: the partial differential equations, despite being written in a covariant fashion, display instabilities and lead to non-causal propagation of signals (they display instabilities both at the computer simulation level, i.e. once discretized, as well as at the exact mathematical level!). This is a theorem based on the analysis of [Hiscock and Lindblom (1985)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.31.725).

**Beyond relativistic Navier-Stokes:** To fix the stability and causality problems of relativistic versions of Navier-Stokes hydrodynamics, we have to look for a more general framework for dissipative relativistic hydrodynamics. The various possibilities, their underlying assumptions and motivations are summarized in [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.15184). A possible (and widely used) alternative to Eckart or Landau versions of the relativistic Navier-Stokes is the so-called "Israel-Stewart hydrodynamics" (later revised and upgraded in [Derivation of fluid dynamics from kinetic theory with the 14-moment approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1554v2)). You can find an introduction to Israel-Stewart hydrodynamics in the recent book by [Rezzolla and Zanotti](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Relativistic_Hydrodynamics.html?id=iYLEAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y): this formulation overcomes the instability problem and is causal (signals, like sound waves, propagate subliminally, namely with a speed less than the one of light), as shown in a seminal work by [Hiscock and Lindblom (1983)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(83)90288-9).

**Why Eckart & Landau's approaches fail:** A simple explanation of why Navier-Stokes does not work in special and/or general relativity is given in ["When the entropy has no maximum: A new perspective on the instability of the first-order theories of dissipation"](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2006.09843): in the formulations of Landau and Eckart, the entropy function turns out not to have a maximum (the homogeneous equilibrium state is an unstable equilibrium point). Therefore, since the fluid wants to maximise entropy, the fluid explodes because entropy "wants" to grow indefinitely.